# Why after a form post back, I get 404?

Tags: 404-error, forms

I am creating a contact form page. Perhaps I am doing it wrong? I have something like

```
<?php
// even when I remove this validation block it fails
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    // do validation ... 
}

get_header(); 
?>
...
<form id="frmContact" action="<?php the_permalink() ?>" method="post">
    ... 
</form>
...
```

I used the same logic in another page and it works ... the URL is correct and if I refresh the page, it works. It just gives 404 on post back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try clearing out the action attribute:
    action=""

Comment: It still gives 404 ...

Comment: What values are you posting? It's probably best to namespace them ... especially if you are processing a form so late in game

Comment: yes ... I remembered ... I think its the "name" key

Comment: That would do it :)

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has something triggered from posting a field with name="name" tried to change it to name="clientname" for example.

Comment: How is that an answer?